# how to make vim format source code correctly

Tags: linux, vim

I'm trying to use vim to edit source code for AutoHotkey.

This is how the source code looks when correctly formatted:

```
if foo
{
    if bar = 1
        callFunc1()
    if bar = 2
        callFunc2() 
    if bar = 3
        callFunc3()
}
```

If I do =G, then this is what vim changes it to:

```
if foo
{
    if bar = 1
        callFunc1()
        if bar = 2
            callFunc2() 
            if bar = 3
                callFunc3()
}
```

I had other formatting problems with this source code that was solved by using `:set cindent cinoptions=+0`, but that does not solve this problem.

Comment: AutoHotkey comes with its own .vim plug for VIM. Check the `Extras\Editors\` directory. Last I tried it was only syntax highlighting. But things might have improved since then.

Answer (score 0):

cindent is generally for C... There are lot of vim extensions for various programming languages, google for them. They often introduce proper syntax indentation.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no indent file for this kind of script, you can use the [indentAnything script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1839).

As stated :

> The IndentAnything plugin is intended
>   to make it easier to write new
>   indentation scripts and/or supplement
>   existing ones.  It makes the
>   assumption that all indentable
>   languages have similar
>   characteristics:
>
> - blocks of code or text over multiple lines
> - continuation lines
> - comments